# Automapper append source list items to destination list

Tags: automapper

I am trying to map `List<string>` property but I want in destination object to always have default value. On the source object list can be empty or it can contain other values.

If the list is empty then the Destination property will contain only the default value that is defined in the constructor.

If the list contains some data, then Source values should be appended in the list.

Here is my code:

```
    List<string> _accessRights;
    public User()
    {
        _accessRights = new List<string>() { "user" };
    }
    public List<string> AccessRights
    {
        get { return _accessRights; }
        set { _accessRights = value; }
    }
```

Here is the example how I would use it.

```
UserModel user = new UserModel() { access_rights = new List<string>() { "power_user", "admin" } };
        User dbUser = Mapper.Map<User>(user);
```

As a result I would like to have `user, power_user, admin` saved in the database. 
If the `access_rights` was `null` then I would expect to have only `user`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the map like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserModel, User>()
      .ForMember(user => user._accessRights, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.accessRights != null ?
        src.accessRights.Union(new User()._accessRights) : new User()._accessRights));
```

Comment: This solves part of the issue. Only part that is missing that I would like to have `user` permission always saved even though it was not passed from `source` object. With your solution when the `accessRights` is empty I do have desired output, but when is not, then I don't have permission `user` saved.

Comment: You could use Linq to union values from `UserModel` and the default list of access rights. This would keep you from having duplicates and keep the map simple. I updated the answer after your comment.

Comment: That solved my problem. It looks like pretty ok solution. Not sure if there are other ways to do it.

Comment: This does not keep the original list values only the destination values.